# Customize SharePoint 2016 App Launcher Tiles

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2016, applauncher

SharePoint 2016 OnPremise now contains the AppLauncher in the upper left corner like Office365 already does.

How can i add/modify/remove those links in an OnPremise-only installation of SharePoint 2016?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requested feature has been implemented with [SharePoint 2016 FeaturePack 1](https://blogs.office.com/2016/09/26/announcing-feature-pack-1-for-sharepoint-server-2016-cloud-born-and-future-proof/) which was release in November 2016. The feature is also shipped with SharePoint 2019 RTM.

Steps to implement custom tiles:

- Check if at least FeaturePack 1 for SharePoint Server 2016 is installed (SharePoint Build 16.0.4456.1002 or above)
- Enable the feature via PowerShell: `Enable-SPFeature -Identity CustomTiles -Url <WebAppURL> -Force`. It is a WebApplication-scoped feature, so it must be enabled and configured per WebApplication
- A hidden list named `Custom tiles` will automatically be created in the RootSiteCollection of your WebApplication. It can be found in `http://<WebAppURL>/lists/custom%20tiles`
- A new tile can be created by adding a new item to the list. The form will ask all necessary information

[image: New tile]

- The new tile will be displayed within 24 hours to the users.
- More configuration-options can be found in Microsofts documentation: [Custom Tiles in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Answer (score 4):

You must have full hybrid integration (hybrid Sites) with SharePoint Server 2016. I worked with Vlad Catrinescu yesterday to get this working. You can 'Add a tile' from the O365 Administration center and it may take 24 to 48 hours to boil back down to on-prem. You cannot directly customize it, the tiles will only come from O365.

EDIT: Here's a picture.

[image]

Comment: This is really sad that its controlled outside the environment and is available only in Hybrid Scenario. A Forceful change to move customer from onpremise to online.

Comment: This changed with Feature Pack 1, where this is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog post, it seems to be impossible in the current version of SharePoint 2016.

http://nikcharlebois.com/enable-the-sharepoint-2016-app-launcher/

UPDATE:  See note above regarding Feature Pack 1.  We got it to work.

Comment: This article is for a preview. Unfortunately i also was not able to find any customization-capabilities in the GUI of SharePoint 2016 RTM. But it might be possible via PowerShell or Programming-APIs. Maybe we can find someone here on StackExchange who can give an answer. I'm sure i will not be the only one asking this :)

Comment: I found other resources also, I did not provide the link to,that says the same thing.  So, I believe it is still not available yet!
Good Luck!